# Sharing access to a search kit display table with non-admin user

Tags: permissions, searchkit

I need to share search kit display tables with Civi users who are not at the admin level. These users have access to view all the contacts in the search, and all tables relevant to the search. I'm using WordPress.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something (is there a better way to share a display table than viewing it and copying the url?) or misunderstanding the Enforce Permissions/Bypass Permissions button.

When I have it set to Bypass Permissions, the help text says "Anyone who can view this display will be able to see all results, regardless of their permission level." But that doesn't seem to be true; when the non-admin users try to access the link, no table appears (not even headers). (And, for some reason I'm not sure about, even for me as an admin the name of the display is grayed-out and unclickable from the main search kit Saved Searches page with the help text "Display has permissions disabled")

When I have the display table set to Enforce Permissions, the non-admin users have the same result; no visible table. This may be expected, since the help text for Enforce Permissions says "Only users with 'All CiviCRM permissions and ACLs' can disable permissions checks" and the users in question do not have that permission.

A workaround would be, rather than using the display tables, just give the user access to Search Kit and let them access the search itself. But I cannot see any way to give access to Search Kit to users.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, in case this is useful for anyone else -- it looks like the answer was that I needed to be embedding my Search Kit search into Form Builder rather than just the using the Search Kit displays.

I found more info on how to do that, with lots of detail about the permissions pieces, in this SearchKit Demo Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ0MEagAdqA (mostly around the 17 to 25 minute mark)

Comment: Thanks for your question and your answer ! very useful